# jsPdf generates blank PDF

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jspdf

I'm trying to generate a PDF of the current HTML page with jsPdf - however it is generating a blank PDF.

This function is being called by ng-click:

```
$scope.getPdf = function() {
    doc.fromHTML($document.outerHTML, 15, 15, {
        'width': 190,
        'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    });
    doc.output("dataurlnewwindow");
}
```

Any idea as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I am assuming the `fromHTML` method performs some sort of task that creates a document fragment, so doc might not be defined, or defined as something invalid

Answer (score 0):

The parens around document appear to be the culprit. Try:

```
$scope.getPdf = function() {
   doc.fromHTML($document.html(), 15, 15, {
    'width': 190,
    'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
   });
   doc.output("dataurlnewwindow");
}
```

Comment: I tried that but it still causes the  same issue. I've updated my question to reflect the current outcome - now jsPDF is generating a blank page.

Comment: You're missing the $ in front of document.

Comment: If you trace the code and step into the fromHTML function does it pass a parameter in from $document.outerHTML?